# How can I call a C++ style exported DLL in C# (Windows Forms) code?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

The DLL file is exported in C++ style with function modifiers added. The interface names exported in the dynamic library are as follows:

Actual function name:`RegPOC_CB`

Interface name in dynamic library:`?RegPOC_CB@@YAHPAUPOC_CB_t@@@Z`

The `RegPOC_CB` function is defined as follows, receiving a `POC_CB_t` structure pointer that stores the callback function.

```
define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

typedef void (*CmdOutCallBack)(char* pAtStrCmd);
typedef void (*RADataCallBack)(const char *src , int len,int type) ;
typedef void (*RVDataCallBack)(const char *src , int len,int type, int width,int high,int rota);

typedef struct
{
    CmdOutCallBack cmdOutCB;
    RADataCallBack rADataCB;
    RVDataCallBack rVDataCB;
    CmdOutCallBack LOCB;
}POC_CB_t;

extern int EXPORT RegPOC_CB(POC_CB_t *pCbFunc);

int RegPOC_CB(POC_CB_t *pCbFunc)
{
    if(gpPOC_cb == NULL)
    {
        gpPOC_cb = (POC_CB_t *)malloc(sizeof(POC_CB_t));
        gpPOC_cb->cmdOutCB = pCbFunc->cmdOutCB;
        gpPOC_cb->rADataCB = pCbFunc->rADataCB;
        gpPOC_cb->rVDataCB = pCbFunc->rVDataCB;
        gpPOC_cb->LOCB = pCbFunc->LOCB;
    }
    InitTime=GetTickCount();  // Record initialization timestamp

    return InitTime;
}
```

I registered the callback function in C# using the following code, but all printing in the implementation of the callback function has no effect when debugging. During single-step debugging, it shows that calling the `RegPOC_CB` function is successful and no error is reported. Why?

```cs
public class Sender(int id)
{
    POC_CB_t callbacks;
    public int Id { get; set; } = id;

    [DllImport("say.dll", EntryPoint = "?RegPOC_CB@@YAHPAUPOC_CB_t@@@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int RegPOC_CB(ref POC_CB_t pCbFunc);
    // Using IntPtr has no effect either
    // public static extern int RegPOC_CB(IntPtr pCbFunc);

    // Define a C# delegate that matches the C++ callback function
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void CmdOutCallBack(IntPtr pAtStrCmd);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void RADataCallBack(IntPtr src, int len, int type);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void RVDataCallBack(IntPtr src, int len, int type, int width, int height, int rota);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void LOCallBack(IntPtr message);

    // POC_CB_t struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POC_CB_t
    {
        public CmdOutCallBack cmdOutCB;
        public RADataCallBack rADataCB;
        public RVDataCallBack rVDataCB;
        public CmdOutCallBack LOCB;
    }

    // Callback function implementation
    public void cmdOut(IntPtr pAtStrCmd)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("call cmdOut");
        var at = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAtStrCmd);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(at)) { return; }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"[{id}] cmdOut Callback: {at}");
    }

    public void rAData(IntPtr src, int len, int type)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("call rADataCB");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        Marshal.Copy(src, buffer, 0, len);
        var data = buffer.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"[{id}] Data: {data}, Length: {len}, Type: {type}");
    }

    public void rVData(IntPtr src, int len, int type, int width, int height, int rota)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("call RecvVideoData");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        Marshal.Copy(src, buffer, 0, len);
        var data = buffer.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"[{id}] Data: {data}, Length: {len}, Type: {type}, Width: {width}, Height: {height}, Rotation: {rota}");
    }

    public void LO(IntPtr message)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("call LogOut");
        var LogStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(message);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LogStr)) { return; }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"[{id}] Log: {LogStr}");
    }

    // call RegPOC_CB
    public void RegisterCallbacks()
    {
        callbacks = new POC_CB_t
        {
            cmdOutCB = cmdOut,
            rADataCB = rAData,
            rVDataCB = rVData,
            LOCB = LO
        };

        RegPOC_CB(ref callbacks);
        // Using IntPtr has no effect either
        //IntPtr pCallbacks = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(callbacks));
        //Marshal.StructureToPtr(callbacks, pCallbacks, false);
        //RegPOC_CB(pCallbacks);
        InitPoc(0);
    }
}
```

I have tried using `ref` and `IntPtr` to pass the structure pointer into the DLL, but the result is the same.

The calling code of the `Sender` instance in [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) is as follows:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Sender s;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = new(123456);
        s.RegisterCallbacks();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple differences (entry point, callback type) between the definitions in C# and C++. Are you sure this is the latest code? Have you checked it?

Comment: @shingo The entry point has been modified. This is another interface of the dynamic library. It was copied incorrectly when copying.
What specifically does it mean that the callback type is different? Does it mean that the delegate function of C# does not match the function pointer defined in C++?

Comment: @shingo 
Indeed. If the dynamic library cannot be modified, do I need to change the definition of `POC_CB_t` in the C# code to this?
`public AtStrCmdOutCallBack LogOutCB;`
I just tried the above code, but there is still no function call print in the output during debugging.

Comment: As written, the otherwise invisible reference to the Sender object must be *static* or passed to GCHandle.Alloc().  That ensures the next garbage collection won't destroy the delegates and make the callbacks fail.

Comment: I just declared the instance of Sender as static, but it has no effect and the function is not called. I updated the question and put the calling code of Sender at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I just tried your code in a console program, it works, so here comes a stupid question: Is the program you are debugging running in debug mode? (Or has the DEBUG symbol been defined?) And are you viewing the output window (not the console window)?

Comment: @shingo This is indeed the case. In the file I just printed the log in the callback function, the callback function was indeed called. But the printing failed. I was debugging in debug mode (F5), and the output viewed in the debugging interface, `immediate window` and There is no output in the `output` window.

This is a farce, thank you very much!